# How to QLOGIN to a node that shared a specific job-id

Tags: linux, unix, sungridengine, qlogin

I have an existing `qlogin` job like this:

```
job-ID  prior   name       user   state submit/start at     queue        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
3530770 0.50500 QLOGIN  jlsmith   r     10/15/2012 14:02:07 mri.q@compute-0-29.local
```

The above job was submitted using standard qlogin command in linux:

```
 $ qlogin
```

What I want to do is to perform another qlogin so that the process
are running in the same node with the above Job-ID `3530770`.

The idea is that if it's done correctly in `top` command I can see the same running
process submitted to the above job-ID.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either

```
qlogin -l h=compute-0-29.local
```

or

```
qlogin -q "*@compute-0-29.local"
```

Should do the job

Answer (score 2):

Based on talking to some HPC specialists at work and some Google searching on the subject (I also wanted to resume a job ID), it's not really possible *if you've already submitted the job*. You can `qlogin -q <node name>` into the node again, but you cannot resume the job on the shell screen.

If you are thinking of starting a *new* qlogin job, but you would like to be able to resume it at some future point, then you can use `screen` to do this.

1. Before you write `qlogin` into the command line at the front-end node, write `screen`. It should completely clear the terminal screen.
2. Now `qlogin` and put in your job script interactively.
3. Once your job has started running and you want to leave for a bit, press and hold Cntl while you press A and D. It should say that your screen was detached and take you back to the front-end node. If you `qstat` now, you should see your job running.
4. When you want to resume the job ID (see the running process on the terminal screen), in the front-end node write `screen -r`. You should be able to see your running process in the terminal again.

Note: if you do this several times and you accumulate multiple screens by accident (happens to me every time), when you `screen -r` you will get multiple choices instead of automatically resuming the one you want. To try each one out, type `screen -r <name of screen listed>` one at a time until you find the one you want (detach as specified above). To get rid of the extra screens, write `screen -D -r <name>`.

Hope this helps.